# Spring Batch - How to execute a second step inside the first step ItemProcessor

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have two tables in the database:

```
Customer Table
id | name 
------------
1  | X
2  | Y

Product Table
id | customer id | name 
--------------------------------
1  | 1           | iphone
2  | 1           | moto
3  | 2           | moto
```

I am using Spring Batch to process the data in these tables. I have a Step to read/process/write each client and a second Step to get the products of each client and generate a text file for each client as follows:

```
file-c1.txt
c1iphone
c2moto

file-c2.txt
c3moto
```

How can I run the second step (products) for each iteration of the first step (customers) or how can I do this in some other way?

Comment: Maybe I am missing the point about writing phase on cliente table so this comment is wrong, but can be a simple JOIN between the tables enough?

Comment: This is a small example. Basically i wanted to do is: Job-A read DB and fetch N rows, for each ROW run JOB-b

In other words, run a second Job for each iteration of the primary Job.